# Filter data without <Fragment> before ReactJS Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hello I try to filter my datas according to their status, the problem is that if I don't put a  before the if, it doesn't want to do it, and if I put a  before, it only displays my datas where the if matches but still displays my .

```
{orders
           .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
           .map((order) => (
             <Fragment>{ order.statut === 'Validé' ?  <TableRow key={order.id}>
               

               <TableCell colSpan={12} >
        <NavLink  className="NavProjet" to={`./settings/${order.id}`}  replace key={order.id} ><Projetfinis type={order.type} key={order.id}>
          <Projetid>#{order.orderid}</Projetid>
           <Projettype type={order.type}>{order.type}</Projettype>
           <ProjetDate> <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">
           {order.time}
            </Moment></ProjetDate>
           <ProjetTitre>{order.nomproduit}</ProjetTitre>
           <ProjetStatut statut={order.statut}>{order.statut}</ProjetStatut>
           <ProjetIcon><MdAdd/></ProjetIcon>
         </Projetfinis></NavLink>


               </TableCell>
              </TableRow> : null }</Fragment>
            ))}
```

If someone have a solution, thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the thing that you want to *put before*? An `<a>` tag?

Comment: For the moment my { order.status === 'Validated'? ...
works only if I put <Fragment> in front of it, however since there is a fragment, it considers that there are still 13 fragments while the filter is only outputting 4, what I would like is a solution to do the if without the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the code to work without the `<Fragment>`, you can change it to this:

```
{
  orders
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
    .map(order => {
      if (order.statut === "Validé") {
        return (
          <TableRow key={order.id}>
            <TableCell colSpan={12}>
              <NavLink
                className="NavProjet"
                to={`./settings/${order.id}`}
                replace
                key={order.id}
              >
                <Projetfinis type={order.type} key={order.id}>
                  <Projetid>#{order.orderid}</Projetid>
                  <Projettype type={order.type}>{order.type}</Projettype>
                  <ProjetDate>
                    {" "}
                    <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{order.time}</Moment>
                  </ProjetDate>
                  <ProjetTitre>{order.nomproduit}</ProjetTitre>
                  <ProjetStatut statut={order.statut}>
                    {order.statut}
                  </ProjetStatut>
                  <ProjetIcon>
                    <MdAdd />
                  </ProjetIcon>
                </Projetfinis>
              </NavLink>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
}
```

But what is the problem with the Fragment? It does not get rendered to the DOM, so it should not interfere with anything else.